# How to store class attribute in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, oop

Is it possible to store value to attribute in class? If so then how?

For example:

```
class Student {
  public $name;
  public $grade; 

  function average() {
     $sum = 0;
     foreach ($this->grade as $key => $value) {
        $sum += $value;
     }
     $avg = $sum/ count($key);
     return $avg;
  }
}
```

How to add values `[math=8, history=9, biology=8]` to attribute and develop method which count average of the grades?

Comment: You fundamentally changed the nature of this question with no explanation.  Not cool.  Are you getting errors or not?  If so, what are they?  And if you are trying to transcribe your code by hand, in the future, _don't_. Always copy/paste your code exactly as-is whenever possible.

Comment: I am totally new in this community.  Sorry for changing code. Your help was really useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to write any code in your class to assign values to `$grade`, because it's marked as `public` (see "[Visibility](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php)" in the PHP documentation), which means code outside the class can access it.

After you create an instance of `Student`, you can just assign that array directly to the `$grade` property.

```
$student = new Student;
$student->grade = ['math'=> 8, 'history' => 9, 'biology'=> 8];
```

---

Instead, if you want to use that array as the default value for any new objects of this class, you can initialize the property to that value at the same time you declare it.

```
class Student {

    public $name;
    public $grade = ['math'=> 8, 'history' => 9, 'biology'=> 8];
    // ...
```

Comment: But somehow is possible to add value directly to class attribute $grades that all new students have this value? can it be array? Thank you for your time

Comment: Right now stuck with DataTime() function. Maybe you now how correctly get attribute value of object?  function mokinioVidurkis () {
        $dabar = new DateTime();
        var_dump($dabar);
        $gimimodat = new DataTime($this->gimimoData); 
        var_dump($gimimodat);
        $skirtumas = $dabar->diff($gimimodat);
        var_dump($skirtumas);
        
        return $skirtumas;

Comment: @Darius that doesn't sound like it has much to do with this Q&A. Do you need to ask a new question?

Comment: yes, but system dont let me do that because this question wasn`t so successful...

Comment: I didn't think you could get question banned over one question with two downvotes. Do you have other deleted questions? They'll count toward a question ban as well if they're downvoted.